# $\cos (n \arccos x)$ factorize

Tags: abstract-algebra

I got to the point that we can express $\cos (n \arccos x)$ through this formula:
$$
\cos(n\cdot \arccos(x)) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k} (x^2-1)^k x^{n-2k}.
$$
It is also quite obvious that this polynomial will have roots.
How to find them and represent it through the formula:
$$2^{n-1} \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(x-\cos \frac{(2 k-1) \pi}{2 n}\right) ?$$

Comment: Look up Chebyshev roots.